# SQLX: cannot put vector of enum into db

Tags: postgresql, rust-sqlx

I have a table

```sql
CREATE TYPE WEEKDAY AS ENUM (
    'sunday',
    'monday',
    'tuesday',
    'wednesday',
    'thursday',
    'friday',
    'saturday'
    );


CREATE TABLE tasks
(
    weekday       WEEKDAY ARRAY
);
```

Following the documentation and other SO questions, I'd expect the following to work

```rust
#[derive(sqlx::Type)]
#[sqlx(type_name = "weekday", rename_all = "lowercase")]
enum Weekday {
    Sunday,
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday,
}


    let weekday: Vec<Weekday> = Vec::new();
    sqlx::query!(
        r##"
        INSERT INTO tasks (weekday)
        VALUES ($1);
    "##,
        weekday
    )
    .execute(&mut **db)
    .await
    .expect("db failure");
```

but I get error `error: unsupported type _weekday for param #1`. I've tried to put `as "weekday: weekday"` in various places (as suggested in other threads), but always was responded with syntax error. How can I make it work?

Comment: In `psql` this `insert into tasks values ('{monday}');` works. So see if you can make `rust-sqlx` do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Argh, after some digging I found the ugly answer.

1. I need to explicitly set type of vector in the binding (`weekday as Vec<Weekday>`)
2. I need to manualy implement trait `PgHasArrayType` - should be derivable by `sqlx::Type`, but enums are not supported at this moment

so in summary the code is

```rust
#[derive(sqlx::Type)]
#[sqlx(type_name = "weekday", rename_all = "lowercase")]
enum Weekday {
    Sunday,
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday,
}

impl PgHasArrayType for Weekday {
    fn array_type_info() -> PgTypeInfo {
        PgTypeInfo::with_name("weekday[]")
    }
}

    let weekday: Vec<Weekday> = Vec::new();
    sqlx::query!(
        r##"
        INSERT INTO tasks (weekday)
        VALUES ($1);
    "##,
        weekday as Vec<Weekday>
    )
    .execute(&mut **db)
    .await
    .expect("db failure");
```